# Convert YYYYMM factor format to YYYY-MM format

Tags: r

I have data which have the format of `YYYYMM` and I wish convert it to `YYYY-MM` format.

exemple :  `201805` should be in the format of `2018-05`

How could I do it please ?

Comment: In which language?

Answer (score 5):

We can use `as.yearmon` from `zoo` to convert it to yearmon object and then do the `format`

```
library(zoo)
format(as.yearmon(as.character(v1), "%Y%m"), "%Y-%m")
#[1] "2018-05"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- 201805
```

Answer (score 4):

I like the idea of using actual dates here.  If the days component does not matter to you, then you may arbitrarily just set each of your dates to the first of the month.  Then, we can leverage R's dates functions to handle the heavy lifting.

```
x <- "201805"
x <- paste0(x, "01")
x
y <- format(as.Date(x, format = "%Y%m%d"), "%Y-%m-%d")
substr(y, 1, 7)

[1] "20180501"
[1] "2018-05"
```

Comment: You were 32seconds faster :) `format(as.POSIXct(paste0('201805', '01'), format = '%Y%m%d'), format = '%Y-%m')
[1] "2018-05"` Day is not required

Comment: @Sotos I'm counting my blessings that Akrun didn't give this answer earlier.  No way to compete in that case :-)

Comment: Haha..noone stands a chance :)

Answer (score 3):

You *could* use regular expressions:

```
data <- "201805"
sub("(\\d{4})", "\\1-", data)
[1] "2018-05"
```

Another variant, using only lookarounds:

```
sub("(?<=\\d{4})(?=\\d{2})", "-", data, perl=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about following one(I am considering that OP need not to perform any checks on its variable's value here).

```
val="201805"
sub("(..$)","-\\1",val)
```

OR to perform substitution with last 2 digits only try following.

```
val="201805"
sub("(\\d{2}$)","-\\1",val)
[1] "2018-05"
```

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to some of the others, but because I find the package useful I will mention it:

```
library(lubridate)

date <- "201805"
format(ymd(paste0(date,"01")), "%Y-%m")
```

Lubridate can make life easy if the formats start to vary.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option albeit a longer one:

```
library(tidyverse)
somestring<-"201805"
stringi::stri_sub(somestring,1,4)<-"-"
somestring1<-"201805"
somestring2<-substring(somestring1,1,4)
as.character.Date(paste0(somestring2,somestring))
```

Result:

```
"2018-05"
```